# how disable adding existing record in has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I add unique index, but record dont save, validation error. I need update tags in my post,existing tags adding to tags with new id, but I need existing tags not to be added

```
    class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tags_posts
  has_many :tags, through: :tags_posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags_posts, :allow_destroy => true, :update_only=>true
end

    class TagsPost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tag, :allow_destroy => true, :update_only=>true
end
```

controller code:

```
def update
      @resource=resource_class.find(params[:id])
      @resource.assign_attributes(resource_params)
      if @resource.save
        render json: @resource.as_json(as_json_resource)
      else
        render json: {errors:@resource.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

      def resource_class
    Post
  end

  def resource_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:user_id,:title,:category_id, :content, :date_of_publication, tags_posts_attributes: [tag_attributes: [:name]] )
  end
```

Comment: Answered the question, did it work?

Answer (score 1):

Add `id` to `tag_attributes`

```
params.require(:post).permit(:user_id,..., tags_posts_attributes: [tag_attributes: [:id, :name]] )
```

That will prevent it from adding again.